# PostgreSQL: Need to display "Ads" every N rows

Tags: postgresql, web

Given, I have table Posts and have table Adverts.
I have a webpage with posts (with infinite scroll).

I need to display row from Adverts table for every N rows from Posts table.

Is it possible to do using a single query?

What I want to achieve:

p01 p02 p03

p04 p05 p06

p07 **a01** p08

p09 p10 p11

p12 p13 p14

**a02** p15 p16

p17 p18 p19

p20 p21 **a03**

...

Comment: Do the Adverts and Posts tables have similar schemas? If not, you're mostly SOL. I'd probably just use two queries.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo you can think of them as they use the same scheme.

Comment: rows can be even in the same table.. just of different type. I'm currently on planning stage.. thinking of best organization of all this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example tables:

```
create table posts (post_id int, post text);
insert into posts select i, 'p_'||i from generate_series(1, 13) i;
create table adds (addv_id int, addv text);
insert into adds select i, 'a_'||i from generate_series(1, 3) i;
```

Insert an `addv` every four `posts`:

```
select post, 
    row_number() over (order by post_id)
    + (row_number() over (order by post_id)- 1)/ 4 rank
from posts
union
select addv, row_number() over (order by addv_id)* 5
from adds
order by 2;

 post | rank 
------+------
 p_1  |    1
 p_2  |    2
 p_3  |    3
 p_4  |    4
 a_1  |    5
 p_5  |    6
 p_6  |    7
 p_7  |    8
 p_8  |    9
 a_2  |   10
 p_9  |   11
 p_10 |   12
 p_11 |   13
 p_12 |   14
 a_3  |   15
 p_13 |   16
(16 rows)
```

You can use `cross join` with `generate_series()` to *rotate* `adds`. You should do this using two ordinal columns. However, if you can assume e.g. that the `addv_id` is less than 10000, use one column for simplicity:

```
select addv_id+ i* 10000 addv_id, addv
from adds
cross join generate_series(1, 3) i  -- 3 number of repeats
order by 1;

 addv_id | addv 
---------+------
   10001 | a_1
   10002 | a_2
   10003 | a_3
   20001 | a_1
   20002 | a_2
   20003 | a_3
   30001 | a_1
   30002 | a_2
   30003 | a_3
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Works excellent! Bonus question.. is it possible to rotate/repeat adverts, like if we have just one advert in table, then every 4 rows this advert would repeat?